# comboBox not showing text but still works

Tags: c#, text, combobox

```
private void FormSellTheBreads_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  formMenu = (FormMenu)this.Owner;

  comboBoxVariantSell.DataSource = formMenu.listBread;
  comboBoxVariantSell.DisplayMember = "Nama";
}
```

I'm a student and my teacher taught me data bindings and this should make text appear on the combobox but it didnt it still works but the text doesnt show i dont really know what to do. This was exactly the same as what my teachers code was.

Comment: What is the type of `.listBread`?

Comment: Assign formMenu.listBread to a variable, set a breakpoint on the line after. When the breakpoint is hit, use the [local window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2022) to examine data, is there data and is there a column or property name Nama?

Comment: We need more information to be able to answer this question. For example, what UI framework are you using (Windows Forms, WPF etc)? How is `this.Owner` defined? How is `comboBoxVariantSell` instantiated and what other property values does it have?